# Local Outlook 2019 JavaScript Add-In

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-2019

I want to create my own Outlook add-in using JavaScript.

As a first step I want to load the xml file as an add-in.

I am running a local installation of Office 2019.

So far I tried:

1. Outlook

   - adding "add Add-ins" to the quick bar (resulting in a disabled button)
2. Word - Downloading the Style Checker demo (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker)

   - running a localhost:1800/demo/ with the xml-file
   - adding to Word "Trusted Add-ins Catalogs Url"
   - the result is, that it is not showing up in word

**My Question is**, how can I add the xml file to my local Outlook 2019 installation, so that I can start working on the JS part? It is fine for me to run this from a localhost url.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question you're asking should be answered by this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing?tabs=windows